# React pass a function to another component

Tags: reactjs, react-component, react-functional-component, react-class-based-component

I want to use a function checkboxes from the class Apps that looks like this:

```
  checkboxes(selecter, id) {
    if (document.getElementById(id).checked === true) {
      this.doboolAPICall(selecter);
    }
  }
```

in another component that's named "Buttonbox" I want to call it like this:

```
<Selectbutton id="photoenabled" name="PhotoEnabled" onChange={() => Apps.checkboxes("PhotoEanbled", "photoenabled")}></Selectbutton>
```

now when I try it out the error is as follows: uncaught error: F.checkboxes is not a function

Comment: Can you state the relationship between your `Apps` and `Buttonbox` component? Or even better if you can give a Minimal reproduceable example

Comment: Send the function as props from App component to ButtoBox like ---- <ButtuonBox checkFunc={this.checkboxes} />

Comment: Also post your minimal code so that others can understand better